# HTML/CSS - cant put li element on the right side

Tags: html, css

I am newbie and I've got a trouble. I have  element with four

elements and I can't put one on the right side.
My code is here:

```
<body>
<header>
    <div id="topmenu" class="navigation">
       <ul class="navul">
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
            <li class="rightbutton"><div><a href="#">Log In/Sign Up</a></div></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

And css is on jfiddle ( I was not able to attach it correctly)

http://jsfiddle.net/EGxWy/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `float:right` on one li element and `display:inline-block` on all li elements.